# Chossing between Prediction vs classification model for dataset having daily record(date value)

Tags: classification, time-series, predictive-modeling

I have a use case, where I have 4 classes based on the score, for example

class 1 : when the score < 10
class 2 : when the score between 11 to 20
class 3 : when the score between 21 to 30
class 4 : when the score > 30

The score value is continous data and is derived from the given aggregated dataset for each day (date) for different stocks.

My training dataset contains both the score and class value for each day.

The problem statement is, I need to build a model which will predict if there will be any movement from the current class to a another class 
(i.e. class 1 to class2 or class 3 to class2 etc.) in the subsequent day.

For this, I thought of below options and want to check for better ways.
Option 1:
1. Build a linear model (using Linear Regression or SVM, NN etc) to predict the score which is required to predict the class movement.
2. Use the predicted score to decide if there will be any change in class based on the range provided above.
3. Build a confusion matrix for the different class (1 to 4) to show the actual vs predicted score
Option 2:
1. Directly Build a multi-class classification model to predict the the class movement. 
2. Build a confusion matrix for the different class (1 to 4) to show the actual vs predicted score.

Since the dataset contains the date and stock name for each day, Is it necessary to use the Timeseries analysis for this use case?
Instead of that can i split the date into year, month & day and use it for training?